Is there a way to update unnamed capturing groups within a Python regular expression to named capturing groups, after the fact?
Lets say i have a regular expression "(\d+)(\w+)". Is there a way to dynamically update this regular expression to name the groups after the fact?
I am trying to programmatically read in regular expressions who have unnamed capturing groups with a format string like number::$1 letter::$2. I'd like to update the regular expression to name the groups from the format string, (?P<number>\d+)(?P<letter>\w+).
Note that I am trying to update the regular expression itself, not the output of matching the expression with some string.
I cant really think of anything to try to get this to work.

Imagine you could turn your original regular expression into something like [{'pattern': '\d+', name: None}, {'pattern': '\w+', 'name': None}], and a function that could turn such a list back into '(\d+)(\w+)'. Now imagine that given the string number::$1 letter::$2, you could use that to change the name values for each dict to the appropriate name.

You can use a regular expression to match all the ( characters that aren't escaped or followed by ?, and insert the corresponding ?<groupname> after it.

This is tricky because if it's escaped, the backslash itself might be escaped, making it a literal. To do it really right you need to embed this in something that can really parse regular expressions.

@chepner I just have the original expression. If it was already broken out in a dictionary, I wouldn’t have this problem in the first place.

@Barmar I tried using a regular expression to extract the groups but like you said it gets complex fairly quickly with backslashes and even potential parentheses inside [ ].

@user3377280 That's my point: you need to parse the regular expression first to get a proper data structure.

Instead of rewriting the regexp, it would probably be easier to deal with this at the other end. Instead of extracting capture groups by name, use the format string to get them by index.

You could locate those ( that are not inside a character class, nor inside a comment (?# ... ), are not escaped, and are not followed by ?, and replace those with the named group syntax.
It is probably easier to actually match the character classes, the comments, the (? sequences, the escape pairs, ... and other lone characters and among those matches locate the ones that are simple ( matches, and replace those.
Here is code you could use:
import re

def name_capture_groups(regex, names):
    revnames = names[::-1]

    def replacer(m):
        return f"(?<{revnames.pop()}>" if m[0] == "(" and revnames else m[0]

    charclass = r"\[\^?(?:\\.|[^\]])+\]"
    comment = r"\(\?#[^)]*\)"
    extension = r"\(\?(?!#)"
    escaped = r"\\."
    normal = r"[^([]"
    tokens = fr"(?:{extension}|{escaped}|{charclass}|{comment}|{normal})+|."
    return re.sub(tokens, replacer, regex, re.DOTALL)



# demo
regex = "(\d+)abcdef(?:hello)(\w+)(?#comment((()[^abc()]"
result = name_capture_groups(regex, ["digits", "name"])
print(result)


Thanks! I got it to work by writing a regex grammar in a parsing library like Lark. This is a much simpler solution.
